# How to get ZoneOffset from ZoneId?

Tags: java, timezone, zone

I am trying to evaluate zone offset value as `int` (like -3, 0 or 3) by giving `zoneId` value, but I cannot do this by following several approaches on SO.

```
private int convertToZoneOffset(final int zoneId) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecondNow);
    ZonedDateTime atZone = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    return ... ?

}
```

What is a proper way for Java 11?

Comment: At present Asia/Kolkata is at offset +05:30. Do you then want 5 or 6 or a message saying the the offset cannot be represented as an `int`?

Comment: A time zone identified by a `ZoneId` encompasses the historic, present and known future offsets from UTC. They are often many. Very many time zones observe summer time (DST) and have a difference of 30 minutes or an hour between the offset in summer and in winter. Do you want the offset used at the current moment?

Comment: If you're dealing with time zones, I'd recommend this instructional (and funny) video: "The Problem with Time & Timezones - Computerphile" https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`ZoneId#getRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getRules--) to get the `ZoneOffset`, from which you can get the hours and minutes if required.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        ZoneOffset offset = convertToZoneOffset(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(offset);

        long seconds = offset.getTotalSeconds();
        long hours = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS) % 60;
        System.out.println(hours);
        System.out.println(minutes);
    }

    private static ZoneOffset convertToZoneOffset(final ZoneId zoneId) {
        return zoneId.getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
+05:30
5
30
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2VmATw)

**The variant using a specific Unix epoch:**

```
private static ZoneOffset convertToZoneOffset(final ZoneId zoneId, long epochSecond) {
    return zoneId.getRules().getOffset(Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond));
}
```

Also, if you need the hours to be rounded off, you can use the following statement in the code:

```
long hours = Math.round(seconds / 3600.0);
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>